# How to connect to another MongoDB database as superuser using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, security, mongodb

The solution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20543505/1420197) works fine:

Instead of doing:

```
$ mongo my_db_name -u superuser -p 1234
```

I do

```
$ mongo admin -u superuser -p 1234 # connecting as super user to admin db
> use anotherDb
```

in shell.

---

Which is the solution in NodeJS?

I tried to connect to `mongodb://superuser:1234@localhost:27017/my_db_name` but I get this error:

> `{ [MongoError: auth fails] name: 'MongoError', code: 18, ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth fails' }`

My code is:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://superuser:1234@localhost:27017/my_db_name",
    function(err, db) {
       if (err) { return console.log(err); }
       console.log("Successfully connected.");
    }
);
```

Note that *superuser* is the omnipotent user that can *write* and *read* rights in **any** database.

If I do `MongoClient.connect("mongodb://superuser:1234@localhost:27017/admin` (replaced `my_db_name` with `admin`) it connects successfully. Why?

How can I connect to the `my_db_name` using `superuser` and the password (`1234`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution would be to use a shell script that is executed from Nodejs side:

```
mongo <<EOF
use admin
db.auth("superuser", "1234");
use another_db
db.addUser({
   user: "test",
   pwd: "12345",
   roles: ["userAdmin"]
});
exit
EOF
```

Then I am able to use the following connection string: `"mongodb://test:12345@localhost:27017/my_db_name"`.

This solution works, but I am still looking for the Mongo native solution.

Comment: I added a native solution which should work for you. By the way, if you are still looking for a better answer for a question you should leave it unaccepted to increase the chances someone else will notice the question :).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Db().db(dbname)`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#id1) method to create a new Db instance sharing the same connection.

So you can authenticate to the `admin` db and change to `another_db`:

```
db.auth("superuser", "1234");
another_db = db.db("another_db");
another_db.addUser({...}
```

Comment: But is this the NodeJS solution? I guess it's a Mongo script... Can you edit your answer providing a small NodeJS script that connects Mongo database as superuser?

Comment: @IonicăBizău: That's the NodeJS solution .. have a look at the [DB().db() documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#id1) that I linked :).

Comment: I remember that I tried that but it didn't work. That's why I ask for full script to be able to test it. If you solve the problem I will accept your answer happilly. :-)